# How would I re write this css with Jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to re write this as jquery or js because I need add a loop to tab-panel for example .tab-panel1, .tab-panel2 in order for multiple tabs to be used on the page and not affect eachother.

```
  <div class="tab-panels<?php echo $count ?>">
    <section id="about<?php echo $count ?>"class="tab-panel">
    </section>
    <section id="contact-sbf<?php echo $count ?>"class="tab-panel">
    </section>
  </div>

.tabset > input:first-child:checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:first-child,
.tabset > input:nth-child(3):checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:nth-child(2),
.tabset > input:nth-child(5):checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:nth-child(3),
.tabset > input:nth-child(7):checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:nth-child(4),
.tabset > input:nth-child(9):checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:nth-child(5),
.tabset > input:nth-child(11):checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:nth-child(6) {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Is the issue that you need to handle an arbitrary number of elements?

Comment: Yeah I need the tab-panel<?php echo $count ?> to incorporate php in the class to loop through it however, I am unable to do that in the css.

Comment: So you want some JavaScript to dynamically create separate CSS rules for classes '.tab-panel1', 'tab-panel2', etc. Is that correct? Maybe include some HTML of the desired finished product? The CSS provided doesn't tell us much.

Comment: Hi @terrymorse I've added some HTML. The goal is to have the css dynamic in order to make the check happen on the class which will be dynamic as well. I'm hoping if I can do the same css check in jquery or js, that i'd be able to add the <?php echo $count ?> next to the class in order for it to affect only specific tabs.

Comment: @ktrea please add some of the finished HTML. You have elements like `.tabset` and `input` that are not represented in your question. Just give a sample of what the finished HTML will look like.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example showing how to show and hide elements using JavaScript, using a `<select>` to control the panel group displayed, and checkboxes to control which tab panels to show.

You should be able to modify this to suit your specific application.

```js
// handle panel group number selection
const GROUP_COUNT = 3;

function handleSelection(select) {
  // get panel group number to be shown
  const showNum = +(select.value);

  // show or unshow each panel group
  for (let i = 1; i <= GROUP_COUNT; i++) {
    const panelGroup = document.getElementById(`panelgroup${i}`);
    if (i == showNum) {
      panelGroup.classList.add('show');
    } else {
      panelGroup.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}

// handle click on a "show children" checkbox
function handleCheck(input) {
  const { checked, value } = input;
  const panels = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-panel');

  // show (hide) all the matching '.tab-panel' elements
  for (const panel of panels) {
    if (panel.dataset.child === value) {
      if (checked) {
        panel.classList.add('show');
      } else {
        panel.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.panel-group {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: none;
}

.panel-group:before {
  content: "#" attr(id);
  color: #aaa;
}

.tab-panel {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid green;
  color: green;
  display: none;
}

.tab-panel:before {
  content: "." attr(class);
  color: #aaa;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="panelsnum">Show panel group number</label>
  <select id="panelsnum" onchange="handleSelection(this);">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="1">3</option>
  </select><br/>
  <label for="checks">Show panels:</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checks" value="1" onchange="handleCheck(this);" /> 1
  <input type="checkbox" name="checks" value="2" onchange="handleCheck(this);" /> 2
  <input type="checkbox" name="checks" value="3" onchange="handleCheck(this);" /> 3
</form>

<div id="panelgroup1" class="panel-group show">
  <div class="tab-panel" data-child="1">group1 first-child</div>
  <div class="tab-panel" data-child="2">group1 second-child</div>
  <div class="tab-panel" data-child="3">group1 third-child</div>
</div>

<div id="panelgroup2" class="panel-group">
  <div class="tab-panel" data-child="1">group2 first-child</div>
  <div class="tab-panel" data-child="2">group2 second-child</div>
  <div class="tab-panel" data-child="3">group2 third-child</div>
</div>

<div id="panelgroup3" class="panel-group">
  <div class="tab-panel" data-child="1">group3 first-child</div>
  <div class="tab-panel" data-child="2">group3 second-child</div>
  <div class="tab-panel" data-child="3">group3 third-child</div>
</div>
```